# Normalization of $y^3=(x^3-1)(x^2+1)^2$, blow up or something else?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I need to normalize the curve $\mathcal{C}:y^3=(x^2+1)^2(x^3-1)$ which is singular at $(\pm i,0)$. I have moved the x-positive one to the origin getting $y^3=x^2(x-2i)^2((x-i)^3-1)$ and I have blown up using the quadratic transformation $(x=x_1y_1;y=y_1)$. Now I have the strict transform $y_1=x_1^2(x_1y_1-2i)^2((x_1y_1-i)^3-1)$ and I need to now the preimages of the singular point in the normalization. $(0,0)$ is given by $y_1=0$ and is still the origin, what about $(2i,0)$? I can't find its preimage. Have I done something wrong?

Please help! Any correction or hint will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We consider a point $p=(p_0,p_1)$ of a curve $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$. The blow up of $\mathcal{C}$ in the point $p$ is the strict transform of the blow up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ in the same point:

$Bl_p(\mathcal{C})=cl(\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{C}\setminus p))$

where $\pi: Bl_p(\mathbb{A}^2)\to \mathbb{A}^2$ and

$Bl_p(\mathbb{A}^2)=\{(q,r)\in \mathbb{A}^2\times \mathbb{P}^1: q-p\in r\}$

The condition $q\in r$ corresponds to the equation
$rk\begin{pmatrix}
x-p_0 && y-p_1 \\
r_0 && r_1 
\end{pmatrix}=1
$, i.e. $r_1(x-p_0)=r_0(y-p_1)$ but it could be more complicated in higher dimension.

There is another useful description of the blow up  $Bl_p(\mathbb{A}^2)$ in terms of the trivializations maps:

$\psi_0: \{r_0\neq 0\}\to \mathbb{C}^2$ sending $((x,y),r)\to ( x,\frac{r_1}{r_0})$

and the inverse is

$\psi_0^{-1}:\mathbb{C}^2 \to  \{r_0\neq 0\} $ sending $z=(z_{00},z_{01})\to (( z_{00},z_{01}(z_{00}-p_0)+p_1),|1:z_{01}|)$

As regards the other chart, one get

$\psi_1: \{r_1\neq 0\}\to \mathbb{C}^2$ sending $((x,y),r)\to (\frac{r_0}{r_1},y)$

and the inverse is

$\psi_1^{-1}:\mathbb{C}^2 \to  \{r_1\neq 0\} $ sending $z=(z_{10},z_{11})\to (( z_{10}(z_{11}-p_{1})+p_0,z_{11}),|z_{10}:1|)$

Thus the trivialization map corresponds to

$\psi_{10}: \mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{z_{01}\neq 0\}\to \mathbb{C}^2\setminus \{z_{10}\neq 0\}$ which sends $(z_{00},z_{01})\to (1/z_{01}, z_{01}(z_{00}-p_0)+p_1)$

This means the blow up can be seen as $\mathbb{C}^2\sqcup_{\psi_{10}}\mathbb{C}^2$.

If you want to blow up more than one point, then

$Bl_{p,q}(\mathbb{A}^2)=\{ ((x,y),r_p,r_q)\in \mathbb{A}^2\times \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1 : (x,y)-p\in r_p, (x,y)-q\in r_q\}$

Thus the blow up in two points can be viewed as gluing of open sets of $\mathbb{C}^2$ in the following way:

$Bl_{p,q}(\mathbb{A}^2)=((\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_0)^{-1}(q))_{(z_{00}^p,z_{01}^p)}\sqcup_{\psi_{10}}(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_1)^{-1}(q))_{(z_{10}^p,z_{11}^p)})
\sqcup 
((\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_0)^{-1}(p))_{(z_{00}^q,z_{01}^q)}\sqcup_{\psi_{10}} (\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_1)^{-1}(p))_{(z_{10}^q,z_{11}^q)})$

Now we are in the position to resolve your singularities:

$Bl_{0,q}(\mathcal{C})=cl(\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{C}\setminus 0))=\{(z_{00}^p,z_{01}^p): z_{00}^3z_{01}^3=z_{00}^2(z_{00}-2i)^2((z_{00}-i)^3-1)\}\sqcup \{(0,0)\}= \{(z_{00}^p,z_{01}^p): z_{00}z_{01}^3=(z_{00}-2i)^2((z_{00}-i)^3-1)\}\sqcup\{(0,0)\}$

in the first chart $(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_0)^{-1}(q))_{(z_{00}^p,z_{01}^p)}\sqcup \{point \  at  \ infinity\}$, while in the third chart $(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_0)^{-1}(p))_{(z_{00}^q,z_{01}^q)}\sqcup \{point \ at \ infinity\}$, $q=(2i,0)$,  we get

$Bl_{0,q}(\mathcal{C})=cl(\pi^{-1}(\mathcal{C}\setminus q))=\{(z_{00}^q,z_{01}^q): (z_{00}-2i)^3z_{01}^3=z_{00}^2(z_{00}-2i)^2((z_{00}-i)^3-1)\}\sqcup\{(0,0)\}= \{(z_{00}^q,z_{01}^q): (z_{00}-2i)z_{01}^3=z_{00}^2((z_{00}-i)^3-1)\}\sqcup\{(0,0)\}$

Thus the inverse image of the exceptional point $0$ of the blow up of $\mathcal{C}$ will be

$\pi^{-1}(0)=\{(0,0)\}$ where $(0,0)$ is the origin of the second chart $(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_1)^{-1}(q))_{(z_{10}^p,z_{11}^p)})$

and

$\pi^{-1}((2i,0))=\{(0,0)\}$ where $(0,0)$ is the origin of the fourth chart $(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_1)^{-1}(p))_{(z_{10}^q,z_{11}^q)})$

These two points corresponds to the transversal intersection between the two exceptional locus of the blow up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ and the strict transform of the curve.

In general there is the possibility this intersection is not transversal, but if you do certain number of blow ups in the intersection points, then you will get a smooth curve that will intersect the exceptional locus in a transversal way. That curve is the resolution of your curve.

If you have some questions, I'll help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will study it and I will let you know

Comment: With indexes in $Bl_{p,q}(\mathbb{A}^2)=((\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_0)^{-1}(q))_{(z_{00}^p,z_{01}^p)}\sqcup_{\psi_{10}}(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_1)^{-1}(q))_{(z_{10}^p,z_{11}^p)})
\sqcup 
((\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_0)^{-1}(p))_{(z_{00}^q,z_{01}^q)}\sqcup_{\psi_{10}} (\mathbb{C}^2\setminus (\pi\circ \psi_1)^{-1}(p))_{(z_{10}^q,z_{11}^q)})$  you mean the coordinates or are you localizing? And what do you mean with $cl$?

Comment: @cartesio No no I mean the coordinates, and $ cl$ is the clousure in the Zariski topology

Comment: Ok I've tried to study and compare it with the explanation in Fulton's book, I have understood but I can't see the nonsingular model... how could I use it? Isn't better to use quadratic transformation?